# StartActivity very slow if called while launcher is active?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service, android-launcher

I am writing a security type app that sometimes needs to be opened from a background service. To open it, I use:

```
  Log.i("MY_DEBUG_TAG_CORE", "Starting Launch");
  Intent i= new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  this.startActivity(i);
  Log.i("MY_DEBUG_TAG_CORE", "Launch Completed")
```

In most circumstances, my application opens almost instantly. However, when the above code is called while a launcher app (TouchWiz Home, Nova Launcher, etc) is active, it takes five to ten seconds to open. I get "Starting Launch" and "Launch Completed" in LogCat, and then the long delay, before the app is launched.

Nothing different appears in LogCat or the console when this delay happens. Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: It might help if you showed some more code from the background service

Comment: I am experiencing similar issue in my app, launching an activity from a service. Did you ever find a solution to that problem?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue while writing my security app. Did you find a solution to this issue

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? Anybody?